# are any versions of AirSim able to run on M1 Mac which ship with Big Sur?

Tags: macos

I want to know if I can run AirSim on an M1 MacBook.

I know that it works on macOS Catalina (10.15). I don’t think I can downgrade this Mac to Catalina so I’m stuck and can’t find anything from the vendor to see if this will work.

Can I expect to install and run run AirSim on a Mac M1?

Answer (score 2):

According to https://microsoft.github.io/AirSim/build_linux.html only Catalina is supported. You can‘t run Catalina on M1.

Comment: I watched a video on Youtube about one guy using UNREAL ENGINE (which is used in AirSim) on Mac M1, but it was too slow.

Comment: @ThiagoCavalcante Running Unreal Engine and running AirSim may be two different things..

Comment: Is this able to run on a VM running Catalina or a different OS?

Comment: @ThiagoCavalcante AFAIK guest OSes in M1 VMs must be ARM versions